# How to implement a Force Sensor

Tags: gazebo-sensor

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi All,

I am wondering how you would implement a simulated force sensor to measure joint torques if the method physics::joint::GetForce(int) is not implemented. If anyone has done this with Gazebo any help would be appreciated.

cheers

Peter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/351/how-to-implement-a-force-sensor/) by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 203 on 2012-12-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

John just committed a new (?) force torque sensor to the issue_16 branch: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/commits/172726f2e6f1cb47e2fc0fbbc60ca61c70ab4b51

So there should be an official working solution in trunk soon.

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-12-04**:
It looks like that's a re-implementation of a feature that used to exist. It's necessary to create a force-torque sensor plugin as pointed to in my answer, but is not a force-torque sensor itself.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-11**:
There is a ticket on bitbucket for creating an actual sensor: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/379/create-a-force-torque-sensor

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

DARPA arm simulator does that, as a gazebo plugin, here:

- [`gazebo_ros_jointFeedback.cpp`](http://svn.thearmrobot.com/darpa_arm_sim_servers/re2darmGazeboPlugins/src/gazebo_ros_jointFeedback.cpp)
- [`components.urdf.xacro`](http://svn.thearmrobot.com/darpa_arm_sim_servers/RobotModel/models/components.urdf.xacro)

Note there was a specific gazebo tag in the URDF (`<provideFeedback value="true"/>`) that had to be used to get ODE to compute the force and torque at a particular point because it does some optimizations that typically prevent it from working.

I don't know if they've written a better implementation in the mean time, but this worked at the time.

**Update:** Note that from @ThomasK's response, the current version of Gazebo may not be able to use such a plugin until, the referenced patch is released.

---

Originally posted by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) with karma: 283 on 2012-12-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on 2012-12-04**:
Okay, thanks. It appears that the algorithm is a simplified Recursive Newton Euler Algorithm (google), basically only working with gravitational component (centrifugal and coriolis forces neglected (no big deal)), calculating the force backward from the tip of the end effector to the base. Correct?

**Comment by [asomerville](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/65/asomerville/) on 2012-12-04**:
Some of the code came from other places, and It's been a while so I don't exactly remember, but I'm sure I didn't specifically account for centrifugal and coriolis force unless it's already baked into GetBodyForce which it may be. I think that comes from ODE's calculations.

**Comment by [PMilani](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/92/pmilani/) on 2012-12-04**:
Okay, what then does GetBodyForce() output? Is it the cumulative force of child links on the COG of the current body, plus external (contact) forces? Your code suggests the cumulative force of the child links is calculated in calculatedForce loop (similar to RNEA) not using the GetBodyForce method

**Comment by [littleghost](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4645/littleghost/) on 2018-06-27**:
Hi, @asomerville, the files can't find anymore, can you post a new link?